# Sending static array in c, catching with pointer

Tags: c, dynamic, segmentation-fault, static-libraries

I am having trouble with my static library I created. Before I moved my main code to the library, everything was working, but when I added the library I segfault and can't figure out why exactly.

I have a function called `addEntry(char * name, char * buildings);`

When I call the function in my main c file, I call it with

```
addEntry(name,building)
```

I declared name as `char *name`, and malloced accordingly

However, I declared building as a static array `char building[256]`

Before I started moving everything to my static library, everything was working but now I am getting a segfault.

Does anybody know what is wrong?

Edit: Here's the code

```
    printf("list building: ");

    while (fgets(building,sizeof(building),stdin) != NULL)
    {
        if (building[strlen(building)-1] == '\n')
        {
            building[strlen(building)-1] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }

    //Everything below I am trying to move into my function addEntry,
    //where everything stays the same, but I have to use the parameters
    //i stated above


    ptr = strtok(building,",");

    while (ptr != NULL)
    {

        strcpy(temp,ptr);
        strcat(temp,"buildingUsers");
        tempFP = fopen(temp,"r");
        fp = fopen(temp,"a");

        if (tempFP == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(fp,"%s",name);
        } else {

            tempREAD = fopen(temp,"r");

            while (fgets(readBuffer,sizeof(readBuffer),tempREAD) != NULL)
            {
                if (strstr(readBuffer,name) != NULL)
                {
                    foundCounter++;
                }
            }

            if (foundCounter == 0)
            {
                fprintf(fp,"\n%s",name);
            } else {
                ;
            }
        }

        ptr = strtok(NULL,",");
        strcpy(temp,"");

        fclose(fp);
        fclose(tempFP);
        fclose(tempREAD);
    }
```

Comment: No, we can't know what's wrong without seeing the code. Post a minimal example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Ill edit in the code now

Comment: Edited the post @PaulGriffiths

Comment: Use a debugger and/or add debug print messages. Stack Overflow isn't a free debugging service.

Comment: You need to show something we can actually compile, a full example with nothing in it except enough to cause your problem.

Comment: I suspect `sizeof(building)` is returning `sizeof a pointer` instead of the array size if `building` is no longer declared in the same scope of where `sizeof` is being called. (but that is just *reading tea leaves* without seeing a [**MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: what are you passing to sizeof pointer or an array? that might make a difference. If you can provide the type of parameters as they are declared as well as what data is contained in the files that'll help. The other thing can be in certain situations when tempFP is null so will be fp and as a result the checks can lead to errors where you do if (tempFP == null)  { fprintf( fp....) }

Comment: building is declared as char building[256]. All the code that isn't shown is getting user input and storing it into a char * name.

Comment: All the code shown above is the working code, it doesn't work if I send name and building as parameters to a function called AddEntry(char * name, char* building) and put all the code below taking out the newline in the AddEntry function @AniruddhDikhit

Comment: We can't help you unless you produce code to reproduce the problem, so voting to close.